# ping google.com not sending any response

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ping

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I tried checking my internet connection by pinging `google` but I only get this statement:

```
PING google.com (216.58.196.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Pinging `localhost` works fine however.

I also checked other ips and websites too. But it is not working for any of them.

Comment: Perhaps you just don’t have internet connection?

Comment: I have internet connection

Comment: Your post is very broad. First: Did it work before? What network configuration do you use? A network manager perhaps? Please add some detail. And is this really the only line printed?

Comment: Yes, It printed only one line with this network. I tried with another wifi network it works fine.

Comment: If you tried it with another wifi network, then it is a problem with your wifi and not the local computer. Do you use a MAC filter or something similar on your router?

Comment: Sorry! I am new in networking. I don't know about the server. Another wifi solved my problem. Now It's ok for me

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue with your AP firewall or device firewall.
If it is the firewall on the ubuntu device, this issue would likely be fixed with these iptables rules: 
`iptables -I OUTPUT -j ACCEPT ## accept outgoing traffic`
`iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type=echo-reply -j ACCEPT ### accept the input of echo replies`

If this does not work, it is most likely your AP firewall assuming you have already confirmed that the device has internet access.